# How to redirect to subdomain but then allow normal use of site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

So I have my site, www.domain.com.

For a week or so I want to direct all traffic going direct to the site to subdomain.domain.com, a little promo page about an upcoming feature. I want visitors to then be able to continue to the site as normal though after they've read it, so a continue to www.domain.com/index.php link.

How can I do that with in the htaccess file? Everything I've tried so far messes up when clicking the continue link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with .htaccess you could use a  302 temporary redirect, but it would be for a whole sub folder as far as I know.

Another way would be to redirect with JS/server site language to the subdomain, create a cookie, then redirect back to www.domain.com/index.php .

the 302 redirect is explained here: [How do I redirect my site using a .htaccess file?](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?)

You would need to have a .htaccess for the root folder point to your subdomain

Comment: Yeah I tried a 302 redirect to subdomain.domain.com which worked but then clicking on the domain.com/index.php link led to subdomain.domain.com/domain.com/index.php which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is only possible if you enable mod_proxy in the Apache config of `domain.com` otherwise URL will change after redirect.

Enable mod_proxy, mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://subdomain.domain.com/ [L,NC,P]
```